# RPi - Python Curses program running at boot does not have keyboard focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-curses

I am trying to write a program that will run when my raspberry pi starts up and will allow me to immediately begin typing things with my keyboard and have it be picked up by the program. I don't want to have to manually start the program when the pi starts. I need to use curses (or a similar unbuffered keyboard input library) because I display what I am typing on a 2x16 I2C LCD, but I also need everything that I am typing to be recorded to a text file.

Right now, I am auto-starting the program at boot by putting a line in rc.local. This works, and the I2C display is correctly showing program output, but it does not respond to keyboard input, and the keyboard input is instead displayed (when I connect the pie to a screen, the goal is to run headless) on an odd console layout that exits when I press enter and says -bash: 'whatever I just typed' command not found.

I have already tried:

1. Setting a timer at the beginning of the program to wait until the pi has fully booted before initializing the curses window and keyboard capture
2. Creating a seperate python program to wait until the pi has fully booted and then running the main script by importing it

Neither of these methods works though, I get the same problem with slight differences.

To be clear, the program works flawlessly if I run it manually from the command line. But there is no keyboard input to the program (or at least not where it is supposed to be inputted) when I autostart the script with rc.local.

My code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import I2C_LCD_driver, datetime, sys
from time import *
from subprocess import call

mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()

for x in range(30): #waits for raspberry pi to boot up
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("Booting Up: "+str(x), 1)
    sleep(1)

import curses
key = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.noecho()
key.keypad(1)
key.nodelay(1)

escape=0
while escape==0:
    #variable initialization

    while 1:
        k=key.getch()
        if k>-1: #runs when you hit any key. getch() returns -1 until a key is pressed
            if k==27: #exits the program when you hit Esc
                break
            elif k==269:
                # a couple other special Function key cases are here
            else:
                inpt=chr(k)
                mylcd.lcd_display_string(inpt,2,step) #writes the last character to the display
                #some more code that handles writing the text to the LCD, which works flawlessly when run manually.

    file.write("%s\r\n" % entry)
    file.close()
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("Saved           ",2)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("F1 New F2 PwrOff",1)
    while 1:
        k=key.getch()
        if k>-1:
            if k==265: #do it again! with F1
                mylcd.lcd_clear()
                break
            elif k==266: #shut down with F2
                escape=1
                break
curses.nocbreak()
key.keypad(0)
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
call("sudo shutdown -h now", shell=True)
```

The line that I have in /etc/rc.local is as follows if that is important:

```
sudo python3 journal.py &
```

and it is followed by the 'exit 0' line. 
Thanks for any help you can provide. I know this is a very specific problem and will be tedious to reproduce, but if anyone knows anything about autostarting functions I would be very appreciative of any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, literally all I had to do (which I did find after some more research on stackexchange, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242639/6901706) is the thread that contained the answer I was looking for) was run my program from ~/.bashrc instead of /etc/rc.local. This method works perfectly, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This should be because of how you called the program:

```
python3 journal.py &
```

You may want to check out [JOB CONTROL](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#JOB_CONTROL) of bash (or your shell) man page:

> Only foreground
>          processes are allowed to read from ... the terminal.  Background processes which
>          attempt to read from ... the
>          terminal are sent a SIGTTIN ... signal by the kernel's terminal
>          driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process.

In short, once curses (or anything for that matter) try to read from `stdin` your process is likely stopped (after it may have already written to your display). Keep it in the foreground to be able to have it use `stdin` (and by extension keyboard).

Side note: Not sure about distro and details of implementation of `rc.local` in your case, but aren't init scripts normally run with uid/gid 0 already (without wrapping individual calls through `sudo`?)

Comment: I'll work on researching Job Control and trying to find a workaround. Do you have any tips on how to keep my python program in the foreground without actually typing out and running the script manually? On the topic of your side note, I don't know if I need to put sudo in the init command, I just did it becuase I thought it might need that to work, although I don't know enough about linux to know if I need it or not. It is likely that I don't.

Comment: The quickest way that comes to mind: Drop `&` if it is OK for you to have just stay in `rc.local` local until your script finishes. You actually really woldn't want background processes (not in the foreground of current console) to keep getting input from your keyboard, that open a host of (also security) problems.

Comment: I have tried dropping &, but when I do that my pi never boots fully on the main display output (I have to SSH into it and change the code of rc.local to get the pi to boot fully again). It gets stuck just after the 'Starting Hostname Service' line.

Comment: "Never fully boot" I suppose means the `getty` (or similar) does not start? Do you expect the system to start `getty` / present login prompt and the keyboard to be available to both your app and login prompt? Or run your application instead of the login prompt? Unfortunately all that is somewhat distro specific. I could see updating `rc.local` (or even `rc.S` or `rc.M`) being an option (on my system). Otherwise `/etc/inittab` could also be of interest. systemd based system would be configured differently again (and is not familiar to me).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into these things.